# Cutomize my Tabbar height Using a external class?

Tags: swift, tabbar

I want to increase my tabbar height. also different screen should be a different height in all application. None of other solution worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using an extension for changing height of tab-bar

```
 class CustomHeightTabBar : UITabBar {
        @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 0.0

        override func sizeOfTab(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
            var sizeOfTab = super.sizeOfTab(size)
            if height > 0.0 {
                sizeOfTab.height = height
            }
            return sizeOfTab
        }
    }
```

Assign this class to tab bar

[image]

In attribute inspector

[image]

It works for me.

Comment: I am looking for an extention like this,...
let me check if it works..@NavinBagul